# Move Button in front of Div

Tags: html, css

I want to move a button in front of a div.  http://demo.gbaus.com/index.html  In the website the GET A Quote button is not clickable unless you click the very bottom.  I want it to be moved to the front so you can click it.

```
posotion: absolute;
float: right;
margin: 0px 50px 54px 0px;
font-size: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
color: #fff;
padding: 17px 25px 18px 25px;
z-index: 9999 !important;
```

Thats the css right now.

Comment: You should provide a jsfiddle next time, so people on this site can learn in the future, not just help one individual site.

Comment: Why are you using together position:absolute *and* float?

Comment: also in your code you are using invalid property's. Unlike you say you use position: absolute, you actually use display: absolute;

Comment: just put the whole page in jsfiddle?

Comment: I made some edits in the console; it looks like you need to change `display:absolute` (invalid) to `position:absolute` and `float:right` to `right:0`. That will bring the button to the front, but you'll need to fix the CSS for the text on the left.

Answer (score 3):

Change your css to this:

```
.quote {
    background-color: #2380BE;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #268BCF, #1A5F8C);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: right;
    font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 50px 54px 0;
    padding: 17px 25px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;

    //Add these
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

I grabbed this from your site, not the code shown in the question. And as said above, remove this "display:absolute"